# Method Hibernate.createBlob() is deprecated from Hibernate 4.0.1 and moved to Hibernate.getLobCreator(Session session).createBlob()

Tags: java, hibernate

Method `Hibernate.createBlob()` is deprecated from **Hibernate 4.0.1** and moved to `Hibernate.getLobCreator(Session session).createBlob()`. Any solution what should I pass inside method `getLobCreator(Session session)`, i.e in place of Session, Or any other solution showing how to retrieve and save an image into DB using Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: Please consider accepting the current answer if it helps to solve your problem or provide a feedback comment if it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this easy tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_quick_guide.htm),

> ### Session Object
>
> A Session is used to get a physical connection with a database. The Session object is lightweight and designed to be
>   instantiated each time an interaction is needed with the database.
>   **Persistent objects are saved and retrieved through a Session object**.
>
> The session objects should not be kept open for a long time because
>   they are not usually thread safe and they should be created and
>   destroyed them as needed.

In Hibernate 4.0+ you can get `Session` object from a `SessionFactory`. Let's write a handy class for this task.

```
package your.company.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Then:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

byte[] bFile = /* load image into byte array */;
Blob image = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(bFile);
/* ? Your actions with Blob ? */

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Let me know, if it works.

Or (assume `Employee` is a POJO with a field `@Lob private byte[] photo;`, binded to the corresponding table):

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

byte[] bFile = /* load image into byte array */;
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setPhoto(bFile);

session.save(employee);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Info from [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/). Here you can find the full example of how to save image into database. And the example of how to retrieve image.

---

**Note**: For Hibernate 4.3+ your code inside `try` block slightly changes. Because class `ServiceRegistryBuilder` is replaced by `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```