# Alternative method for Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream())

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on file upload. I have this piece of code in my Contoller.

```
try {
    Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream()); // error here!! 
    document.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
    document.setContent(blob);
    document.setContentType(file.getContentType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is, The method createBlob(InputStream) is undefined for the type Hibernate. I'm using Hibernate 4 and this method doesn't seem to exist in it. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051290/method-hibernate-createblob-is-deprecated-from-hibernate-4-0-1-and-moved-to-hi

Answer (score -1):

Hey what you should use is:

```
try {
    Blob blob =Hibernate.getLobCreator(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()).createBlob(file.getInputStream());
    document.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
    document.setContent(blob);
    document.setContentType(file.getContentType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should do it I guess

Comment: what is this sessionfactory here? sessionfactory is unresolved.

Comment: changed the code. either use getCurrentSession or createSession